# Internal logic of the small étale topos of an algebraic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lo.logic, arithmetic-geometry, topos-theory

If we consider the internal logic of the small étale topos of an algebraic variety, is the variety's geometry reflected in it? For instance, how different are the internal logics for the étale topoi of a supersingular and an ordinary elliptic curve over an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic?

Comment: I guess one important thing to note is that the kind of logic preserved by morphisms of schemes is only the 'geometric part' of the logic.  That's because maps of schemes don't induce logical morphisms of topoi, but rather geometric morphisms.  This means that a lot of logic exists but isn't invariant under maps.

Comment: I must say that I disagree with Harry’s comment, geometric logic will survive. Higher first order logic will be forgotten, but geometric logic is not a small fragment of information. Yet, I find the question and the comment of Harry vague enough to be very much subject to opinions.

Comment: Far from being the best source, Giacomo Tendas master thesis, discusses the topic and has the pro of being a quite "short and compact" reference: https://etd.adm.unipi.it/theses/available/etd-11222017-094128/unrestricted/tesi.pdf.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti That's what I said!  I meant that some of the logic isn't invariant under maps of schemes.

Comment: @HarryGindi, very good! I apologize for the misunderstanding.